# Tag merge / synonym request: [bug-tracking] → [issue-tracking]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Amazingly we have almost 5 times more [bug-tracking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-tracking) questions than [issue-tracking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracking) ones, 57 and 17 respectively.

I'm aware that bug tracking is not *exactly* the same thing as issue tracking (some perceive it as a subset of), but all questions are actually on issue tracking.

So could we merge [bug-tracking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-tracking) questions into [issue-tracking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracking), and make them synonyms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been completed: [bug-tracking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug-tracking) has been merged into and made a synonym of [issue-tracking](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracking).

Comment: Since you did this merge, what do you think about doing the same with the 5 questions tagged [tag:bug-report]? I don't know how valuable a tag about bug reports is, and the 5 current questions seem to be about practices and processes involving issue tracking and issue resolution. 2 of the 5 are also dual tagged with [tag:issue-tracking] already, so there would only be 3 affected questions.

Comment: @ThomasOwens They appear to be discussing two different concepts: [tag:issue-tracking] is about the process of tracking bugs and problems, whereas [tag:bug-report] is about writing an actual bug report. Compare to a question about VCS vs. a question about code.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I took a closer look, and that does seem to be the case. Perhaps they both need a good tag wiki (a lot of tags do, I think, though). The only questionable question is [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115388/automated-statistical-analysis-of-bug-reports-crash-reports) which seems to be more related to issue tracking process and metrics rather than users writing bug reports or developers handling a bug report.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I agree: was easy enough to fix.